# Script to reset printer settings to black and white

Tags: powershell, printing, colors

I am new to the whole scripting scene if I'm honest. I have done various things with batch files in the past, but have been looking at PowerShell.

As it is I really don't have any idea where to begin or if what I want to achieve is even possible.

My boss is after getting printing costs reduced so need to look at being able to set a printer default of black and white, a user then has to manually select colour through preferences and then it will automatically revert back to a default of black and white.

I have been looking at various things online today and cant seem to find anything specific to this requirement, so not sure it is even possible.

I have considered the possibility of either a logon script that forces the print settings back or some form of task that will run say every hour in the background.

We use UTAX devices, but they are rebadged Kyocera.

The printers are connected to PCs via network, but there is no server involved. Each printer is a local install on each PC, no shares or anything like that.

PCs are running mix of Win7 and WinXP.

Something I've also considered is two instances of the printer installed - 1 for colour and 1 for black and white, naming them to reflect what they are. But I'm not convinced this will take off due to people being set in their ways for printing.

The driver version we have to work with is UTAX v6.0.2212. You can set profiles, but the factory default is colour and also if the user logs on and they change to colour from the printing default of black and white and forget to revert back then it remains on setting of colour.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should not have to use a script at all. You should be able to set the default to black and white on the print server and have it default to that setting every time something is printed. The printer vendor should be able to assist with this. (As an aside, this question is more appropriate for ServerFault than StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

I happened across your posting yesterday whilst I was looking for a similar application.
One of my clients is attempting to reduce their printing costs, specifically by reducing the number of colour prints that are produced.

We also thought about having 2 printers for each physical printer eg.
   HP LaserJet (Colour)
   HP LasreJet (Mono)
But felt that this was a bit of a heavy handed approach to seomthing that should be relatively simple to resolve !

As such I was looking for a methodology to allow:-

a. Automatically set the Printer to Mono at Startup

b. Allow users a rapid way to switch to Colour, if they really need to print in Colour

c. Revert back to Mono after printing

So after much head scratching I managed to produce a VB.NET application that sits in the System Tray as an icon.
This application can be started in the Login Script or Startup folder.
Ith then forces the current Default Printer to Mono
Double Clicking the System Tray icon sets the current Default Printer to Colour mode
A 60 second countdown then starts, after which the printer is reverted back to Mono.

I am hoping that this will be sufficient for my clients needs and will reduce the number of accidental colour prints.

Let me know if this would be of interest to you !

James

Comment: Hi James, that would be great if you didn't mind pointing me in the right direction. Thanks.